# How to make a list, that has a trailing newline (`Chr$(11)`) after the number?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

The APA style guidelines dictates, that the table caption must be formatted like that

> Table 23
>
> *This table contains numbers and is very interesting*
>
> ```
> +--------------------+----------------+
> | column 1           | column 2       |
> +--------------------+----------------+
> | 1.23               | 34.343         |
> +--------------------+----------------+
> ```

**The problem**

How to make a list, that has a trailing newline (`Chr$(11)`) after the number?

It would be nice, to have define a 1-level ListTemplate, with numbering format "Table %1" with a newline (not new paragraph) after the table number. Unfortunately Word seems to understand only two TrailingCharacters: wdTrailingSpace and wdTrailingNone.

I know, that I can manually put that lousy character. But I need to investigate a myth:

> When used appropriately, Word's styles are powerful enough, that by
>   merely changing style definitions (without VBA/manual editing) table
>   captions can be automatically translated from APA-style to style, when
>   the word "Table" sits on the same line as the table's caption.

"Point & click" answers and VBA-based are equally welcome.

Comment: I don't know much about APA, but I just wanted some clarificaiton on the "myth". Is the myth that using styles alone, you can switch from a layout where you have "Table n" above the caption text (APA style) to a layout where they are on the same line? That's what the other part of your question suggests, but I wasn't completely sure whether that _is_ the myth, is part of the myth, or whether the myth says something else altogether. re. chr(11), I don't believe you can put it in the "number format"- Word displays it as something else, and strips it on save to .docx.

Comment: @bibadia It is a myth. I am under an illusion(?), that MS Word styles are so powerful, that can turn APA-style tables (with newline) into "normal" tables, where the word "Table" is on the same line, as the table's caption. Apparently **it is** an illusion, nothing more. And it is such a shame, since they put so much effort into the fields, bookmarks, list templates and styles.

Comment: Yes, there's a lot of work in any large WP package, but if there is no overarching design or there are compromises to accommodate existing features or data, the resulting inconsistencies can be particularly frustrating, and you end up in trouble every time you push things slightly beyond what the designers really had in mind. That's my experience of Word, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the myth is concerned, one approach you may not have tried is based on styles. What you do is define a character style (let's call it "listlf") and apply it to a hard return (which you would still have to insert either manually, or possibly as part of a complete numbered list paragraph inserted via autocorrect or auto text (not sure about feasibility there).

Then you either "reveal" the line feed by setting the style's text formatting to not hidden, or hide it by setting the text format of the style to hidden.

But how that works with word's other numbering/TOC features I'll have to leave you to find out :-)

Comment: Ingenious! (But a little hackish ;-) ). Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it certainly is a kludge and best avoided:-)